# Oracle SQL Developer Windows Server 2003 install

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I install and run Oracle SQL Developer on a windows 2003 seerver or does it need to be an client (XP) OS?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28240_03/install.htm), the recommended minimum OS's for Windows is:

Windows 2000-Service Pack 4
Windows XP-Service Pack 2
Windows 2003 R2

So I would say if you have R2 installed, you should be good to go.

Comment: agreed, I have used SQL developer on windows 2003 r2 without any problems for quite some time

Comment: It is Java based so runs most places where you can run an up-to-date Java JDK